# How to detect incorrect spellings in a text file using Python?

Tags: python, spell-checking

I am doing an exercise where I have to find out what are the incorrect spellings present in the text dataset using Python. I have checked multiple blogs but all of them show how to autocorrect incorrect spellings. I don't want to autocorrect it, I just want to separate the incorrect spellings from the dataset.

**Sample Dataset:**

```
1. Kurtas for women
2. parti wear dresses
3. denim jeans
4. overcot
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1. parti wear dresses
2. overcot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [pyspellchecker](/questions/tagged/pyspellchecker), at each line, you can check if any of their words are [`unknown`](https://pyspellchecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html?highlight=unknown#spellchecker.SpellChecker.unknown) and if so, keep the line and [`write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) it to a new file. Eventually, you can also [`load_words`](https://pyspellchecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html?highlight=load_words#spellchecker.WordFrequency.load_words) (*custom ones like* `Kurtas`) to the dictionary in order to not be flagged as "misspeled".

```
#pip install from spellchecker
from spellchecker import SpellChecker

sp = SpellChecker() #language="en" by default

# add on more custom words if needed 
sp.word_frequency.load_words(["Kurtas"])
    
with (
    open("file.txt", "r") as in_f,
    open("newf.txt", "w") as out_f
):
    for l in in_f:
        if sp.unknown(l.split()):
            out_f.write(l)
```

Output (*newf.txt*) :

```
parti wear dresses
overcot
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `nltk`'s `words` which contains a `list` of 236736 words in lower-case:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('words')
from nltk.corpus import words
correct_words = words.words()

some_words = ['Bike', 'happy', 'woman', 'parti']
incorrect_spelling = []
correct_spelling = []
for _word in some_words:
    if _word.lower() not in correct_words:
        incorrect_spelling.append(_word.lower())
    else:
        correct_spelling.append(_word.lower())

print(f'correct: {correct_spelling}')
print(f'incorrect: {incorrect_spelling}')
```

Outputs:

```
correct: ['bike', 'happy', 'woman']
incorrect: ['parti']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pyspellchecker` [library](https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/) and have it correct each line. Then compare each original line to the corrected line. If the lines are not equal, a correction has been made.

```py
from spellchecker import SpellChecker

spell = SpellChecker()

def isLineCorrect(line):
    correctedLine = []
    for word in line:
        correctedLine.append(spell.correction(word))
    return (line == correctedLine)

>>> isLineCorrect(["kurtas", "for", "women"])
True

>>> isLineCorrect(["parti", "wear", "dresses"])
False
```

You can split a sentence into words using `.split()` on a string:

```py
sample = "kurtas for women"
sampleList = sample.split()
#sampleList is now ["kurtas", "for", "women"]
```